# TestNG - Invoke multiple testng.xmls in different projects, from a base testng.xml configuration file

Tags: testng

I used TestNG framework, in order to do the functional testing of my application. My project's structure is given below.

```
+Project A
|-----------smoke-testng-group.xml
|
|
+Child Project B
|-----------testng-group-1.xml
|
+Child Project C
|-----------testng-group-2.xml
```

I have specific testng.xml in Projects B,C which contains functional test scripts for that projects. Now I want to create a new project A in the same directory level as Project B,C- which has a smoke-testng-group.xml file. If I run this smoke-testng-group.xml file, it should internally invokes the testng.xmls in the Project B and C.

Is there any way to achieve this feature in TestNG ?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest XML files with the `<suite-files>` tag:

```
<suite-files>
  <suite-file path="./test1.xml"/>
  <suite-file path="./test2.xml"/>
</suite-files>
```